# Rest API Returning HTTP Status Code

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes

I have a scenario where my API application contacts external datasources and for this particular example, my API requests a list of colours from the external datasource. Sometimes the datasource doesnt have these colours and returns a plain text response of "There are no options to display" with a HTTP status code of 200 OK.

What i am wondering is what status code i should return to the client which is consuming my API in this scenario? A 404 not found or 204 no content...? Im not sure what would fit best.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it valid not to return any colours? In which case your original `200` may be the right status code to use.

`204` is normally used to indicate success, but the client need not update any information it holds; deleting or updating a resource for example are valid times to use `204`.

`404` seems wrong if the same URL is being accessed, in your scenario it sounds like the state of resource may change overtime (and it may be empty), but it always exists.

Comment: So what your saying is that a 200 could be right if its valid that no colours are returned. I think i will go with that then. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: In a nutshell, yes :-), glad you found the answer helpful!

Comment: yep, `200` with empty list of results is the right approach imho